# Beautifulsoup how to parse soup.find_all contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This `soup.find_all` returned

```
[<span class="flight-number sp-g-tooltips" data-bundle2="Flight Details"  title="">5J  892</span>, <span class="flight-number sp-g-tooltips" data-bundle2="Flight Details" title="">5J  900</span>, <span class="flight-number sp-g-tooltips" data-bundle2="Flight Details" title="">5J  902</span>]
text1=soup.find_all("span", class_="flight-number sp-g-tooltips")
```

Question: How can I parse the text inside like 5J892 5J900 5J902 and store in an array?

Comment: `lines = [span.get_text() for span in text1]`

Comment: thanks depperm its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text1=soup.find_all("span", class_="flight-number sp-g-tooltips")    
lines = [span.get_text() for span in text1]
```

List comprehension will iterate over each span in `text1` and return the text of that span